# laravel SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect decimal value: 'buy_amt * 0.00097812555575316' for column 'price' at row 1 error

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to update the entire data, but I need to divide the exchange rate by the margin rate on the purchase price, and data format error occurs.

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect decimal value: 'buy_amt * 0.00097812555575316' for column 'prod' at row 1
>   (SQL: update prod set value = 10, price = buy_amt *
>   0.00097812555575316 )

my code:

```
DB::update("update prod set value = ?, price = ?,  ",
            [
                $datas["value"],
                "buy_amt * ".(1+($datas["value"]/100))/$datas["price"],
            ]);
```

prod table

`price value datatype DECIMAL 
buy_amt datatype INT`

```
price | value | buy_amt
11    | 10    | 10
22    | 10    | 20
```

Comment: Its working for me. Did you try running this sql vai phpmyadmin "update prod set value = 10, price = buy_amt * 0.00097812555575316"

Comment: I didn't install phpmyadmin. I want run laravel update query...

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code

```
"buy_amt * ".(1+($datas["value"]/100))/$datas["price"]
```

will yield a string which wont fit into the price field in database which is a number

You meant this

```
$buy_amt * (1+($datas["value"]/100))/$datas["price"]
```

?

Comment: I want SQL) 
update prod set value = 10, price = buy_amt * (1+($datas["value"]/100))/$datas["price"]

Comment: Can I get buy_amt column value?

Comment: What is the datatype of buy_amt column? Also, make sure buy_amt is rightly named. Also, make sure how many decimal values does the price column allows. Also, the 'value' fields look likes a date field where you are setting a number

Comment: what about value field?

Comment: value field also DECIMAL datatype

Comment: could you and a create script of your table to the question please

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem...

```
    DB::table("prod")
        ->update([
            "value" => $datas["value"],
            "price" => DB::raw("buy_amt * ".(1+($datas["value"]/100))/$datas["price"]),
        ]),
```

Need to use DB :: raw to have the query calculate.